# Написание функции для нахождения среднего арифметического

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать метод на JavaScript, который будет принимать 9 параметров в виде целых чисел и выводить на экран их среднее арифметическое. Спасибо.

```js
$('#button_one').click(function calculate(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9){
    a1 =  parseInt($('#a1').val());
    a2 =  parseInt($('#a2').val());
    a3 =  parseInt($('#a3').val());
    a4 =  parseInt($('#a4').val());
    a5 =  parseInt($('#a5').val());
    a6 =  parseInt($('#a6').val());
    a7 =  parseInt($('#a7').val());
    a8 =  parseInt($('#a8').val());
    a9 =  parseInt($('#a9').val());
    var result = (a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9) / 9;
    $('#result-text').html(result);
}
```

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать для решения проблемы? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Comment: С текущей постановкой вопроса это не "помогите", а "напишите за меня".

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin  А почему именно 9 аргументов? В JS можно в функцию передавать любое количество аргументов.:)

Comment: У меня не получается передать параметры именно в саму функцию. В var - могу, а в функцию не получается. На w3c искал подобное - не нашёл.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, `var f = function(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9) {/* ... */}`. Проблема-то в чем?

Comment: А вот если у меня есть 9 разных input-полей в html-странице, мне передавать значение каждому параметру функции отдельно?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, тогда вам нужно задавать другой вопрос (про input).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, потому что в задачнике сказано ровно 9. Ни больше и ни меньше.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно написать функцию, которая будет принимать любое количество аргументов. Например

```
<!DOCTYPE html />

<html>

<body>
    <script>
        function average() {
            var sum = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < arguments[i]; i++ ) sum += arguments[i];

            return sum == 0 ? sum : sum / arguments.length;
        }

        alert( average( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) );
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Но вы также можете написать функцию, указав ровно девять параметров, а в функции проверять, действительно ли передано 9 параметров.:)

Например,

```
function average( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i )
{
    if ( arguments.length != 9 ) /* сообщить об ошибке */
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ничего личного, но учебные задания должны решаться самостоятельно. Только по этому минусую правильный ответ.

Comment: Решил написать скрипт по-своему, но, судя по всему я такой каши заварил...

Comment: Всё впорядке. Добавил в шапку код. По нажатию кнопки должна выполняться функция, которая парсит из input-поля значения, складывает и делит на 9. Код, разумеется, не работает. Где я допустил ошибки?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Зачем вы пишите parseInt(9);? Достаточно просто написать 8.:)  И не надо писать this.a1. Вы можете просто в вычислении суммы написать paseInt( a1 )

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin В данном случае this относится к элементу, которое является целью события. Уберите this. Это неправильно.

Comment: Так, стоп. Давайте сначала :) Значит есть функция, которая должна принимать 9 параметров из моих девяти <input>. Эти параметры объявлены в шапке функции. В теле функции эти параметры принимаются из инпутов, складываются делятся на 9 и передаются в id "result-text". Или я что-то неправильно понимаю? Обновил код в шапке темы.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Я не знаю, что вы пытаетесь сделать, но в теле функции просто надо сложить 9 параметров и поделить их на их количество. Как вы передаете аргументы функции? Это же у вас обработчик события, не так ли? Если вы хотите получить значения из полей, то в функции должны обратиться к полям.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow,  ага, всё, теперь понял. Подскажите ещё, как парсить данные из input-полей в шапке функции?Так — function calculate(parseInt($('#a1')),... ?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin  Как я понял, вы должны внутри функции взять эти девять значений из девяти элементов input.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow именно

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вы ещё тут?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Здесь вам не тут, как сказал Черномырдин.:) Почитайте второй ответ. он полезен.:)

Answer (score 3):

> метод .., который будет принимать 9 ... целых чисел и выводить на экран их среднее арифметическое

Значит, пишем ф-ю, принимающую 9 аргументов и умеющую выводить на экран:

```
function mean(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9) {
    // здесь будет магия вычисления среднего арифм.

    $('#result-text').html(result); // допустим, вывод сделан правильно
}
```

Подозреваю, что про ровно 9 аргументов в задании написано, чтобы вам стало лень их перечислять раз за разом, и вы задумались над решением без перечисления аргументов. Такое и предлагаю ниже.

Просуммировать все элементы массива удобно, используя метод  [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), который сводит массив к одному значению. В функциях JS внутри всегда доступен *массиво-подобный объект* [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), содержащий переданные в функцию аргументы. Воспользуемся этим объектом, чтобы не перечислять `a1..a9`. Поскольку `arguments` – это не настоящий массив, понадобится немного цирка с передачей его как параметра методу `reduce()` настоящего (пустого) массива.

Итак, **среднее арифметическое** от массива `arguments`:

```
var result = [].reduce.call(arguments, function(p,c){return c+p;}) / arguments.length;
```

Проверка и вызов этой ф-ии в задании не описаны, но в вашем коде вы написали получение значений из полей формы. Чтобы 9 похожих строк не повторять, стоит использовать цикл, в котором собирать введённые значения в массив:

```
var i, args = [];
for( i = 1; i<=9; i++) args.push( parseInt( $('#a'+i).val())); // #a1..9
```

Теперь в массиве `args` эти девять значений. И передать их в ф-ю для среднего арифметического можно тоже, не перечисляя:

```
mean.apply( {}, args);
```

Проверку/вызов ф-ии повесьте, как и было, в обработчик нажатия на кнопку. Надеюсь, соберёте это в одно целое. Должно получиться не больше 10 строк.